# TransactionInterop.GetDtcTransaction() throws ArgumentNullException... sometimes

Tags: c#, oracle, transactions, transactionscope, distributed-transactions

I'm occasionally getting this exception, and don't seem to be able to find anything here on SO or google that can shed some insight as to how to debug this.

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: transaction
   at System.Transactions.TransactionInterop.
                        GetDtcTransaction(Transaction transaction)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open()
   at RetrieveMessage() ...
```

My code is fairly straightforward. `RetrieveMessage()` is a call to pop a message off a queue, but that isn't relevant since this fails just trying to open the connection.

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required,
                                            TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10)))
{
    message = RetrieveMessage();
    // ...
    scope.Complete();
}

//...

public Message RetrieveMessage()
{
    using (var cnn = new OracleConnection(ConnString))
    {
        cnn.Open(); //sometimes fails???
        //... execute a stored procedure that calls dbms_aq.dequeue()
    }
    //... return dequeued message or null if queue is empty
}
```

My connection string looks like the following: `Data Source=abc;User ID=test1;Password=test1;Pooling=true;Validate Connection=True`

ODP.NET: version 2.112.1.0, .NET Framework 3.5 SP0

Why wouldn't there be a transaction available when I've explicitly created one already?

Comment: Is this the full stack or have you skipped some frames? what version of ODP.NET are you using? also, can you give us your connection string? do you need transaction enlistment?

Comment: Can we see the body of the `RetrieveMessage()` method? There must be a line where it says `.Open()` on some `OracleConnection` instance. How is that instance set up?

Comment: Simon, Jeppe, I've added the info you requested. There's no additional frames omitted, and I've listed my connection string and ODP.NET version.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this happens when the TCP port that the client is trying to use is closed by an agent other than the database server or the client.  We've been able to simulate this by using TCPView to close all connections on port 1521 between client and server and then trying to open a connection within the same process.  In the real world, we believe that an internal firewall is closing the connections due to inactivity.  Short of preventing the connections from being closed, though, I have not yet found an actual solution to this issue.

Answer (score -1):

If it only sometimes fails, try something like this:

```
while (true){
    if (ConnString == null)
        continue;
    var cnn = new OracleConnection(ConnString);
    if (cnn == null)
        continue;
    cnn.Open()
    //... execute a stored procedure that calls dbms_aq.dequeue() 
    break;
}
//... return dequeued message or null if queue is empty
```

Sorry, I don't know much about "Transactions", so that's all I can help

Comment: I appreciate the effort you took to answer, but my code is throwing an exception, so that's not really a complete solution. Also, there's no reason for me to block in a tight spin loop like that anyways - at the worst, your code could spike the CPU the way it currently is written. Ideally, I'd like to understand the cause of the exception and fix the scenario so that it doesn't throw one at all. Your answer does deserve a downvote.... but I'll leave it.

Comment: Actually m12 the voting mechanism is encouraged here... while a comment is helpful for improving posts it shouldn't be expected as mandatory.  Also keep in mind that typically down votes come from other users, not the poster of the question.  There are plenty of experts here on SO so if you can admit you don't know much about a topic it's probably best to leave to someone else - or be prepared for downvotes.